# Class 'PHPMailerOAuth' not found

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have installed PHPMailer 6.0 and intend to use it to send emails using a gmail account with oauth. The phpmailer package was installed using composer and i have added the oauth files. My composer.json is below :

```
{
"require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
    "psr/log": "^1.0",
    "league/oauth2-google": "^2.0",
    "ext-mbstring": "^0.0.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "^1.5",
    "league/oauth2-client": "^2.2"

}
```

}
I have created an app on the google developer console and also gotten a refresh token,user id and secret (not shown here )..the code i am using to initiate the library is shown below :

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailerOAuth();
```

I am however getting an error shown below:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailerOAuth' not found...
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it slightly wrong, try the following instead.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;

$mail = new OAuth();
```

See the example here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/v6.0.1/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps

Comment: I used the example. Using $mail to be an Oauth object was causing issues.

Comment: Yeah, normally you put PHPmailer in that variable. Hopefully that example helped abit.